# Cannot deploy functions to firebase because firebase was not found in the stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

It's the first time I've used Firebase and I'm following a little dated tutorial and fixing what doesn't work, but this completely confused me.
`firebase serve` works as intended, but when I try `firebase deploy` it gives me the not so helpful:

> !  functions[api(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
> Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs

After I tried `firebase functions:log` the result is:

```
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/handlers/users.js:9:18)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2020-09-14T13:26:12.668Z ? api: Could not load the function, shutting down.
2020-09-14T13:26:13.524442204Z E api: Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function cannot be initialized.

2020-09-14T13:26:13.610364Z E api:
2020-09-14T13:27:58.923381Z I : 
2020-09-14T13:27:59.372665Z I :
2020-09-14T13:27:59.897431Z N api:
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: Provided module can't be loaded.
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase'
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: Require stack:
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: - /workspace/handlers/users.js
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: - /workspace/index.js
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: - /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: - /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/index.js
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/handlers/users.js:9:18)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-09-14T13:29:18.205Z ? api: Could not load the function, shutting down.
2020-09-14T13:29:19.621396169Z E api: Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function cannot be initialized.

2020-09-14T13:29:19.737208Z E api:
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "busboy": "^0.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I can't find why is firebase not found in the package.

Edit: this is my

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const FireBaseAuth = require('./util/fbAuth');

const {
    db
} = require('./util/admin');

const {
    getAllMeows,
    postOneMeow,
    getMeow,
    commentOnMeow,
    likeMeow,
    unLikeMeow,
    deleteMeow
} = require('./handlers/meows');
const {
    signUp,
    login,
    addUserDetails,
    getAuthenticatedUser,
    uploadImage
} = require('./handlers/users');

// meow route
app.get("/meows", getAllMeows);
// post one meow route
app.post("/meow", FireBaseAuth, postOneMeow);
// with route parameter and not protected 
// even without having an account
app.get('/meow/:meowId', getMeow);
// delete meow route
app.delete('/meow/:meowId', FireBaseAuth, deleteMeow);
// like a meow route
app.get('/meow/:meowId/like', FireBaseAuth, likeMeow);
// unlike a meow route
app.get('/meow/:meowId/unlike', FireBaseAuth, unLikeMeow);
// comment route
app.post("/meow/:meowId/comment", FireBaseAuth, commentOnMeow);

// signUp route
app.post("/signup", signUp);
// login route
app.post("/login", login);
// add details route
app.post("/user/", FireBaseAuth, addUserDetails);
// used for the feed route
app.get("/user", FireBaseAuth, getAuthenticatedUser);
// uploadImage route
app.post("/user/image", FireBaseAuth, uploadImage);

// turn it automatically to different routes
// https://kittn-me.com/api/
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Also the error complains with my `/handlers/users.js:9:18)`
So here is also:

**users.js**

```
const {
  admin,
  db
} = require("../util/admin");

const config = require("../util/config");

const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const {
  validateSignUpData,
  validateLoginData,
  reduceUserDetails
} = require("../util/validators");

... (other functions) ...
```

Comment: It looks like you have a mistake in your functions code. Can you post the minimal `index.js` with which you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'd also recommend upgrading to an up to date tutorial, such as https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0

Comment: Of course. Thank you for the tutorial.